# SQLite Case When clause not working correctly

Tags: sqlite, sum, case

I have a `transactions` table like this in SQLite:

| id | date | transaction_type | volume | price | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65 | 1697846400 | buy | 100 | 32000 | 1600 |
| 66 | 1697846400 | buy | 100 | 2300 | 69 |
| 67 | 1697846400 | buy | 100 | 2300 | 69 |
| 68 | 1697846400 | buy | 100 | 23456 | 703 |
| 69 | 1697846400 | sell | 100 | 20000 | 600 |
| 70 | 1697846400 | sell | 100 | 20000 | 600 |
| 71 | 1697846400 | sell | 100 | 20000 | 1000 |
| 72 | 1697846400 | sell | 100 | 12000 | 300 |

I want to calculate the cashflow for each day which consists of `in_flow` and `out_flow` of the cash calculated based on `transaction_type`. The desired result is:

| date | in_flow | out_flow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1697846400 | xxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxx |
| 1697500800 | xxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxx |

In which:

- `in_flow` = Sum of all `transaction value` with `transaction_type` of 'sell' of the `date`
- `out_flow` = Sum of all `transaction value` with `transaction_type` of 'buy' of the `date`

`transaction value` is calculate by `transaction_type` as:

- `buy`: `volume` * `price` + `commission`
- `sell`: `volume` * `price` - `commission`

And this is the query I have come up with so far:

```sql
SELECT t.date,
    CASE 
        When t.transaction_type = 'sell' THEN 
            sum(t.volume * t.price) - sum(t.commission)
    END as in_flow,
    Case
        When t.transaction_type = 'buy' Then 
            sum(t.volume * t.price) + sum(t.commission)
    End as out_flow
From 
    transactions as t
WHERE
    date = 1697846400
Group By t.date;
```

But it somehow only works for `buy` transaction:

| date | in_flow | out_flow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1697846400 | NULL | 13210541 |

I tried to change the condition for `sell` transaction to `LOWER(TRIM(t.transaction_type))='sell'`, the result remains the same.

Everything is fine when I query only the sell transactions:

```sql
Select date, sum(volume * price) - sum(commission) as in_flow
From transactions
Where transaction_type = 'sell' And date = 1697846400
Group By date;
```

| date | in_flow |
| --- | --- |
| 1697846400 | 7197500 |

Any idea of what I have done wrong?

I tried:

- Changing the order of `in_flow` and `out_flow` in the query
- Changing the condition for `sell` transaction to `LOWER(TRIM(t.transaction_type))='sell'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using the aggregate function `MAX()` :

```
SELECT date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'sell' THEN total_price - commission END) AS in_flow,
       MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'buy' THEN total_price + commission END) AS out_flow
FROM (
  SELECT date, transaction_type, sum(commission) as commission, sum(volume * price) as total_price
  FROM 
    transactions
  GROUP BY date, transaction_type
) AS S
GROUP BY date;
```

Using your method, the `CASE` Clause must be inside the aggregate function `SUM()` not the opposite :

```
SELECT t.date,
    SUM(CASE 
        When t.transaction_type = 'sell' THEN 
            t.volume * t.price - commission
        END) in_flow,
    SUM(CASE 
        When t.transaction_type = 'buy' THEN 
            t.volume * t.price + commission 
        END) out_flow
From 
    transactions as t
Group By t.date;
```

Result :

| date | in_flow | out_flow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1697846400 | 7197500 | 6008041 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/V3w7aNYH)